# Obtain necessary Data from a formatted text file in C

Tags: c

Good day! So, I've gone through a lot of similar questions here but none are quite similar to what I have I guess or maybe I just can't seem to apply them to my specific context. So, my problem is basically reading data from a text file that contains information about a playlist:[Textfile content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzm1i.png)

I have created a struct for the playlist and a struct for songs. I'm trying to insert the playlist along with its necessary info into an array of playlists, and each playlists has an array of songs. I'm trying to obtain the necessary data from above to place them in their respective struct attributes/fields. So far, this is my function for loading data:

```
void load_playlists(PLAYLIST plists[10],int *plists_index)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("playlists.txt","r");
    if(isFileEmpty(fp) == 1)
    {   
        fclose(fp);
        printf("File is empty!\n");
    }
    else
    {   
        char buffer[256];
        fgets(buffer,256,fp);
        sscanf(fp,"Total Count of the Playlists\t\t\t\t%d",plists_index);
        if(*plists_index == 0)
        {
            printf("There are no Playlists!\n");
            fclose(fp);
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0;i<*plists_index;i++)
            {
                sscanf(fp,"Name of Playlist %*d\t\t\t\t\t%s",plists[i].name);
                sscanf(fp,"Number of Songs in Playlist %*d\t\t\t\t%d\n",plists[i].song_count);
                fgets_songs(fp,plists[i]);
            }
            printf("Successfully loaded data!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Pardon me but I don't quite know how to approach the problem given that the text file is also being written to (I have already done this successfully)

Comment: `sscanf(fp, ...`?

Comment: Your compiler should be shouting at you: The leading `s` in `sscanf` is for *string*. The `sscanf` "reads" from a string, not a ***f***ile.

Comment: On another note, you don't need multiple spaces or tabs. The `scanf` family of function will interpret any single space in a format string to skip zero or more space in the input.

Comment: You *must* check the value returned by `scanf` (and all the `*scanf` family) to know if it assigned any data at all to `*plists_index` or to `plists->name`

Comment: Should I be using fscanf instead? And remove the fgets?

Comment: No, use `fgets` to read from the file. Then `sscanf` to parse the buffer initialized by `fgets`. And of course you need to read the lines in the loop of course.

Comment: Ohhhhh so basically a loop until end of line using fgets? And inside the loop, I do all those stuff including sscanf?